# Checking for data before inserting into MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

I am creating an SQL script that will add specific entries to the DB when run on a new environment. But I want to have to INSERT query insure that the data doesn't already exist before trying to insert it.

The query I came up with looks sound to me. But for some reason it gives me a syntax error. And yes I have RTFM'ed it. And I have Googled it. Based on other examples that I have seen (even here on Stack Exchange) it looks right to me. Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong?

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO my_model (status, name) VALUES ('active', 'bbc')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM my_model WHERE name = 'bbc')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do that.  You could try using MERGE:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545593/how-to-insert-with-where-clause

Comment: general tip: if you get an error message, show it to us. Then RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html   `INSERT` does NOT have a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Is `name` a unique key?

Comment: Does your `name` column have a unique index on it? If so, you could use the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plain `INSERT` doesn't allow a `WHERE`. If the primary key is `(status, name)` then use `INSERT IGNORE` as @aynber exists. If not, try `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO my_model (status, name)
SELECT 'active', 'bbc'
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM my_model WHERE name = 'bbc');
```

`DUAL` is a system-supplied one-row table, used to guarantee one row of results for something like `SELECT 'active', 'bbc' FROM DUAL`. It's an Oracle "invention" but supported in MySQL. You may be able to drop the `FROM DUAL` from the query; I don't have MySQL today so I can't test it to be sure.

Comment: I ended up using this: INSERT INTO my_model (active_status, name) SELECT 'active', 'bbc' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM my_model WHERE name = 'bbc')

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO my_model (status, name) select('active', 'bbc') from my_model
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM my_model WHERE name = 'bbc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) instead of `NOT EXISTS`, if `name` is a primary/unique key. This will not insert anything if it hits a duplicate key error. You can also use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if you want to update a column if the row already exists.

Answer (score 0):

in sql i would create a stored procedure
not sure if you can in mysql

if  !(SELECT name FROM my_model WHERE name = 'bbc')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO my_model (status, name) VALUES ('active', 'bbc')
END