# Insert data into SQL database using Where clause

Tags: c#, sql, database, where-clause

How can you add data to a specific row in a database, using the `where` clause.

Here is what I tried:

```
"Insert into table1 (name, address) values ('" + textbox1.Text+ "', '"+textbox2.Text+"')
 where (name ='"+textbox1.Text+"')"
```

Comment: What exactly "did not work"? What error did you get?

Comment: What's windows form in here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert with where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545593/how-to-insert-with-where-clause)

Comment: If you try to use where in INSERT may be what you really want is UPDATE. Make sure of it first.

Comment: NEVER contatenate SQL strings with data from user input. It will open you up to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Takarii good point. Learn about passing parameters with your command.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, never ever concatenate strings for database input. It leaves you wide open to SQL Injection attacks. See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information

Secondly, you don't do inserts with a `WHERE` clause. You could do an `UPDATE` with a `WHERE`

Examples:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)

UPDATE TABLE SET col1 = val1, col2 = val2 WHERE col3 = somevalue
```

for example in your case, you would want to write this for an insert (including parameters)

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, address) VALUES (@textbox1,@textbox2)"; 

SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("connection string", sql);

query.Parameters.AddWithValue(@textbox1, textbox1.Text);
query.Parameters.AddWithValue(@textbox2, textbox2.Text);
```

If you know the database field type, instead of using `AddWithValue`, instead use this syntax:

```
query.Parameters.Add(@parametername, SqlDBType.Type,size).Value = somevalue;
```

where SqlDBType.Type is the database field type (eg VarChar, Int, VarBinary etc) and `size` is the value of the field. If my DB field was VarChar(500), then my parameter setup would be

```
query.Parameters.Add(@parametername, SqlDBType.VarChar, 500).Value = somevalue;
```

you can replace the sql string with the following if you want to update rather than insert. Note, update records using an identifier - it would be a bad practice to use `name` as your `WHERE` clause.

```
sql = "UPDATE table1 SET name = @textbox1, address = @textbox2 WHERE xyz";
```

Parameters prevent users from putting unexpected values into boxes allowing for unauthorised code to be run. Using a concatenated string as you currently are could enable an attacker to compromise your entire database

Comment: Upvoted but I would suggest using [Parameters.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of AddWithValue so that you can specify the SqlDbType of your parameter. AddWithValue has been known to cause some issues on certain scenarios AFAIK based on old related questions.

Comment: only reason i did that was due to not knowing what the dbtype was. Otherwise, i would always add with sqldbtype.type, ill update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

you can't insert with a 'where' clause inseert is for adding new records. If your updating then use:

```
Update table1 set 
name = '" + textbox1.Text + "',
address ='" + textbox2.Text+ "' 
where (name ='"+textbox1.Text+"')
```

or insert should be:

```
  "Insert into table1 (name, address) values ('" + textbox1.Text+    
 "','"+textbox2.Text+"')"
```

however make sure everything is validated against sql injection. or parameterize the above.

Comment: its probably better to demonstrate parameterisation rather than provide a solution using the same flaws as the original user.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a where clause for inserting a record into SQL Server database using `INSERT` statement.  You should change your code as below to make it work:

```
"Insert into table1 (name, address) values ('" + textbox1.Text+ "', '"+textbox2.Text+"')
```

Two possible forms of a SQL insert statement are as below:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);


INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

You can learn more about `INSERT` SQL statement here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp