# Insert into query with where clause

Tags: c#, mysql

Case: I'm trying execute a query in C# with MySql.Data.MySqlClient, which containts INSERT INTO, i'm getting an error(see below):

[image: Error]

Database table:

[image: Database table]

What im trying to achieve: I want to insert into a new record with: "value_id(Auto Increment)", "machine_id" "tag_name", "int_value", "real_value" and "bool_value";

I have the following code:

*Retrieving machine ID

```
private void getMachineID()
{
    string connStr = "";  
    string ipAdressID =  "'" + machineIP + "'";
    string basicQueryID = "SELECT machine_id FROM machine WHERE machine.machine_ip LIKE ";
    string totalQueryID = basicQueryID + ipAdressID;

    //Create connection
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    //Query command
    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    //Assign string to query
    cmd.CommandText = totalQueryID;
    //Open connection
    conn.Open();
    //Get result ID from machine where IP adress = machineIP and write to machineID variable.
    machineID = (int)(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Code to insert into the record:

```
try
{
    string connStr = "";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO waardes(machine_id, tag_name, int_value, real_value, bool_value) VALUES(@machineID, @tagName, @intValue, @doubleValue, @boolValue)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tagName", tagName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intValue", intValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doubleValue", doubleValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@boolValue", boolValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineID", machineID);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: So what is the problem? And why need a `Where` for an `insert`? Do you mean update?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert Where query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query)

Comment: Is it a `INSERT INTO .... FROM ... WHERE x = z`?

Comment: AFAIK you need to use  `UPDATE` query if you want to update existing records with condition i.e `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @RahulHendawe ahhh.. the OP wants to update a record o_O

Comment: If updating a record, the `where` clause should use an `AddWithValue` as well, not a concatinated string for the machine ID.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by that @rmjoia, all my data comes from my WPF application. That means i dont want to compare other tables with eachother, i want to compare my C# variable with a row in my sql table in this case. Also i dont want to update a record, i want to store the variables(records every 10 seconds) i've got in C# in my sql database,

Comment: @NielsStenden I thought you wanted to insert something on one table, from other table. Apparently you want to update a record. ignore my question.. I was questioning your intent because wasn't clear to me.

Comment: I'm sorry im totally wrong, i see the problem now, thank you guys anyway!

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `INSERT` with where clause.

Take a look at this question: [How to insert with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545593/how-to-insert-with-where-clause)

Maybe, you can create an `IF` inside your app to verify your parameters before executing the `INSERT` statement.

Based on your query, I believe you need an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE waardes SET tag_name = @tagName,
  int_value = @intValue, real_value = @doubleValue,
  bool_value = @boolValue WHERE machine.machine_id LIKE %1%
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

There can be no Where clause used with Insert. However you can use Where when you are using Insert Into. In your statement I suppose you are missing the Select From before your Where clause.

Consider the example:

```
INSERT INTO tableNameDestination
SELECT feild(s),... 
FROM tableNameSource
WHERE Condition
```

In your case:

```
INSERT INTO waardes(tag_name, int_value, real_value, bool_value) VALUES(@tagName, @intValue, @doubleValue, @boolValue) Select field1, field2, field3, field4 from machine WHERE machine.machine_id LIKE " + "'" + machineID + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use ***where*** in *insert* statement, because insert statement is used for adding new rows to table. you better use *update* statement.