# MySql IF exists select ELSE insert

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have been suffering at this for two hours now. I want to select or insert a record. If the record exist select his ID else insert it and get the new inserted ID. For now I'm trying to run this but I still get an error

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Domains WHERE Domain = @domain)>0 
THEN 
    (SELECT Domain_ID FROM Domains WHERE Domain = @domain) 
ELSE        
    INSERT INTO Domains(Domain_ID,Domain,Disabled,Description) VALUES(@Domain_ID,@Domain,@Disabled,@Description);
```

Comment: Why query for count(*) ? just query for domain match, if there will be non-empty result, return it else insert data.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a Procedure?

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of MySQL syntax (so I won't post this as an answer), but I believe you want something along the lines of `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Domains WHERE Domain = @domain)`... instead of `SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Domains WHERE Domain = @domain)>0`

Comment: I did try if else, if exists and stuff like that.. I ended up with the code you see and I keep getting an error on the insert.. I'm howping I get an answer because I don't know anything about MySql

Comment: For anyone else that is suffering with something like this. Because I don't know much of MySql I desided to go with simple querys insert, select, update, delete and do my logic programmaticaly. I will need to make a lot of requests to the data base and since I'm using ASP.NET I hope it won't be too slow..

Answer (score 6):

Your case is missing an End

```
Case when (something) then (Some)
else (another thing) end
```

Anyway, your else must return a select, an insert won't return anything.
if you want to insert if not exist and then return the value inserted (or return if exists)
do this:

```
INSERT INTO Domains(Domain_ID,Domain,Disabled,Description) VALUES(@Domain_ID,@Domain,@Disabled,@Description) where not exists (select 1 from Domains WHERE Domain = @domain);

SELECT Domain_ID FROM Domains WHERE Domain = @domain
```

This will insert if not exists, and then return. If already exists, won't insert, and return the value

**Edit Jan 2016**

The last query won't work on `MySql`, it is a `MSSQL` syntax

Comment: AFAIK, `CASE` should also have a `THEN` right before `END` if that makes sense.

Comment: MySQL does not support `INTO ... WHERE`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the impact on performance and caching, if Domain_ID is an `auto_increment` field, a simple way to achieve the specific result you want is to use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause of the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Domains
    (fld1, fld2, fld3)
    VALUES(....)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

See the tail section of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).