# PHP PDO - MySQL INSERT with WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, insert

Can someone give me a kick in the right direction with this:

```
    $sql='INSERT INTO table (name,data,other,datetime) VALUES (?,?,?,NOW()) WHERE id=?;';
    $pds=$database->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $pds->execute(array($a,$b,$c,$id));
```

what are I doing wrong here?

Note: I've INSERTED before successfully using PDO. The only difference is the WHERE id=?...

thankyou

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query) out

Comment: What's your problem? Why are you using `WHERE`?

Comment: :) I just read what you said.... I need UPDATE... so sorry...

Comment: thankyou guys... I'll be smarter in the future... appologies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you mean `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET    `name` = ?,
       `data` = ?,
       `other` = ?,
       `datetime` = ?
WHERE  `id` = ?
```

Comment: :) cheers... appreciated...