# Is it possible to insert value in table based on parameter value

Tags: mysql, database

```
String sql = ("insert into registration(pic) values(?) where email='"+Email+"' ");
```

i get error :error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where email='yyy@ymail.com'' at line 1

Comment: You may want to see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/485062/637283

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert Where query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use UPDATE query to pass it like

```
String sql = "UPDATE registration SET pic = ? WHERE email = '" + Email + "'";
```

Syntax for UPDATE query is

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert query format should be,

`"insert into tablename (columnname) values(coulmnvalue)"`

OR

```
"update registration set pic='' where email='"+Email+"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. that is impossible.

Either you want:

```
insert into registration(pic) values(?)
```

Which will give you a new row;

Or you want an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE registration SET pic = ?
WHERE email = <EMAILYouWant>
```

Which will update an existing row where email = the record with the email you want to update the pic column.