# Mysql Query - insert new data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `t` and `t1`.
Say that `t` contains the following data

```
id  name  a  b   c  o   p
1  'John' 1  1   1  23  5
```

and `t1`

```
id1  a1  b1   c1   o1
1    6   7    2    23 
2    9   3    7    23 
3    25  7    12   2
```

I am looking to get the table `t` after some operations as the following example :

```
id  name  a  b   c  o  
1  'John' 1  1   1  23 
2  'John' 6  7   2  23  
3  'John' 9  3   7  23
```

My purpose is insert new columns into t where `t1.o1=t.o` .

Any idea ? I need to use stored procedure ?

Comment: There is no column named `o` in table `t1`.

Comment: you can copy equal records using below sql
`code`INSERT INTO t SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.o=t.o;
<br>
try it. hope that will work..

Comment: Please show exact table schema for table `t` as `CREATE TABLE ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
insert into t (name,a,b,c,o,p) (select name,a1,b1,c1,o1,p from t1 inner join t on t.o=t1.o1);
```

Assuming you still need column p in table t.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efb65/1

*just noticed the sequence in the resulting table so updated the answer accordingly, assuming auto increment in t.id*
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a97c06/1

Otherwise you will need to drop the column first and then insert values.

```
ALTER TABLE t DROP p;
insert into t (name,a,b,c,o) (select name,a1,b1,c1,o1 from t1 inner join t on t.o=t1.o1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddccc/1

Comment: According to what the user requested in the example, the ID column should have no duplicate values, but that's not the case in your fiddle.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano yes just noticed that and updated the answer, thanks

Comment: @melc Why do we need to select the value for p column, since that is not asked in the question? thanks !

Comment: @ChristosPaisios you are right it is not specified. The resulting table does not mention column p at all, so assumed that maybe it is required to remove the column. Also, if the column is excluded null values will be inserted which may be fine depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the data you want from table `t1` to table `t`, using this code:

```
INSERT INTO t (name, a, b, c, o)
SELECT t.name, t1.a1, t1.b1, t1.c1, t1.o1
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t on t1.o1 = t.o
```

You didn't say if the `id` column of table `t` has the [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) option enabled. I suppose this option is enabled.

Comment: It is little tricky. There is no `id` column available in `t1`. Secondly the `id` column in `t` contains non duplicate values.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli Mmm..I fixed my mistake. Yes, you are right. I need to review a little bit the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell for sure without seeing the exact table schema for table `t`, but assuming that `id` column is an `auto_increment` column and that `p` column is `NULL`able

```
INSERT INTO t (name, a, b, c, o)
SELECT t.name, t1.a1, t1.b1, t1.c1, t1.o1
  FROM t1 JOIN t 
    ON t1.o1 = t.o;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e5b8/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/831f8/1)

```
SELECT @rownum := 0;
    INSERT INTO t
    SELECT t.id+(@rownum := @rownum + 1), t.name, t1.a1, t1.b1, t1.c1, t1.o1, t.p 
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t on t1.o1 = t.o;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tableName
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.a, t.b, t.c, t.o
FROM t
INNER JOIN t1 ON t.o=t1.o1
```

`tableName` is the name of the table, in which you want to insert your data. The query under the insert into statement, selects the data you want to insert in your table.

If you need to insert this values to table t, then you should use the following code:

```
INSERT INTO t (id, name, a, b, c, o)
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.a, t.b, t.c, t.o
FROM t
INNER JOIN t1 ON t.o=t1.o1
```

Comment: Could I use the code above if tableName = t ?

Comment: @user3014966 No as it is, it needs some changes. Give me a few seconds to post the corresponding code.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you [MySQL Insert Where query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query)

```
INSERT INTO t
SELECT t1.o1 
FROM AnotherTable 
INNER JOIN t on t.o=t1.o1
```

Comment: What about other columns?