# How to write insert with where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table1 with only two columns `id` and `password` and so i had to insert values with `id` and `password` where `id` not like 'ADMIN%'...
I tried my query as below:

1. `insert into table1 values('','') where id not like 'ADMIN%'` (doesn't work)
2. `insert into table values('','') select id,password from table1 where id not like 'ADMIN%'` (doesn't work)

Both queries didn't work. please help !!

Comment: Where are the data you want to insert ? In another table ?

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

Comment: What is the question? Did you set properties and values for those two columns?

Comment: okio@ No to the same table !! I should be able to insert id's with password into a table named table1 except when id=admin

Comment: Eric @ But i wanted to limit the insertion with a condition when id != admin

Comment: yeah i did. Both the values are strings

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html   `INSERT` has no `where` clause.

Comment: i don't have any existing records to update...i wanted to enter new users with id's with a single limitation for ID. Is it possible?

Comment: Simple: Don't run an `INSERT` statement for things you don't want inserted.

Comment: Is my question wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

insert into table ('id', 'password'); select id,password from table1 where id not like 'ADMIN%'; semicolons...

Try this...

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
insert into table (id, password) select id,password from table1 where id not like 'ADMIN%'
```

As per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL INSERT does not work with the WHERE clause. please check:

[MySQL Insert Where query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query)