# INSERT query WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, where-clause

My code is

```
$queryinsert = mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO studentdata (offsiteleft)
        VALUES ($m_offsiteleft)
        WHERE studentid = '$name'
        ") 
    or die("Error querying database (Offsite minutes INSERT query) ".mysql_error());
```

Giving me this error

```
Error querying database (Offsite minutes INSERT query) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE studentid = '31'' at line 3
```

Comment: I guess you need update not insert

Comment: Do you want to update an existing query? Then use `update`, not `insert`. `insert` does not have a `where` clause.

Comment: so if i use UPDATE do i have to do UPDATE INTO ?

Comment: Try changing $m_offsiteleft for '$m_offsiteleft'

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query

Comment: @user3429811: Look up the `update` syntax in the doc.

Comment: `UPDATE studentdata SET offsiteleft ='$m_offsiteleft' WHERE studentid = '$name'`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE studentdata
SET offsiteleft = $m_offsiteleft
WHERE studentid = '$name'
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know about UPDATE