# Insert data into same table from two different phpfile

Tags: php, mysql

My insert database i have a table named:

> table1 with 4 columns
>
> user | id | roll |class

I have 2 php files `table1.php` and `newadd.php`. I have inserted `user`, `id`, `class` value in `table1` via `table1.php`.

I want to insert `class value` in same table via `newadd.php`, but when I run the files from localhost values are inserted perfectly, but in different row, not in same row.

My query is:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (class) VALUES ('two') WHERE id=123;
```

but it is not working..what should i do?

Here is my code

```
<?php
    include('insertjoincon.php');
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (class)
    VALUES ('two') WHERE id=123";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hYe7g5pe  here is another php file ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert Where query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT makes a new row, but you need to change the already exicting one

"UPDATE table1 SET class='two' WHERE id=123";

Answer (score 1):

Use update statement in newadd.php instead of insert