# Data not being sent to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an image uploading feature which stores the file name in the database and the photo in a folder called `uploaded`. These photos are being moved to the `uploaded` folder but for some reason I cannot save the file name in the database.

- I have also ensured I have connected to the db and have all my columns referenced correctly. I am receiving no errors, the data is just not being stored in the database.

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['pp_submit'])){
      session_start();
          $file = $_FILES['pp_file']['name'];
          $ppf_type = $_FILES['pp_file']['type'];
          $ppf_size = $_FILES['pp_file']['size'];
          $ppf_tmpname = $_FILES['pp_file']['tmp_name'];
          $ppf_err = $_FILES['pp_file']['error'];
      $var = $_SESSION['id'];

     if($ppf_err > 0){ header('Location: ../profile.php');}

      move_uploaded_file($ppf_tmpname,"../uploaded/".$file);
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (profile) VALUES ('$file') WHERE id = '$var'");


  if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
  echo "Item added successfully.<br/>";}
  else
  { echo "Item addition failed.<br/>"; }
  header("Location: ../profile.php?id=$var");
  }
  ```

**My question is:** Why isn't the file name passed through the database?

- I am also curious as to why `move_uploaded_file()` is working but not the query directly below it.

Comment: `INSERT` with a `WHERE` clause? You are creating a new record. Surely you mean `UPDATE`?

Comment: Check `mysql_error()` after issuing the query. Besides, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Look into PDO or MySQLi and especially prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert Where query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query)

Comment: and also make sure that the 'uploaded' folder doesnt get served to the public, since that would probably allow for execution of files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be an update query instead of an insert query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile = '$file' WHERE id = '$var'");
```

Also note that:

- You're using a deprecated API. Consider switching to the `mysqli_*` functions or using PDO.
- You're wide open to SQL injection attacks. Consider using prepared statements.

Comment: Don't worry, I am definitely not finished yet. As for mysql_*, well blame the web hosting. I'd also like to know why `INSERT` does not work in this case? The field was empty previously.

Comment: `INSERT` inserts a new record, `UPDATE` updates an existing record. Whether or not the field is empty doesn't matter.

Comment: Ahhh ok, so a new instance would be `INSERT`, then any altercations (data change) to the instance after would be executed with `UPDATE`.

Comment: Why blame the web hosting? I'd be suprised a web hosting only allows the mysql_ library. If that really is the case, I'd change to a different hosting immediately.