# Insert POST Variable into Mysql depending on SESSION Variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (location) WHERE social_id='".$_SESSION["FBID"]."' VALUES ('".$_POST["location"]."')";
```

So the Location value comes from a form, however, the WHERE is needed obviously because it needs to go into the correct row for the user.
This doesn't work, maybe someone knows if hyphens are misplaced?

Comment: Are you sure you want an insert? does your users table only consist of a location ? I think you want an update don't you? You also shouldn't insert POST variables directly. First validate it's not some bad snippet trying to fetch records from your database.
Also you should place your where at the end of the statement

Comment: Thanks Frank, that was it. Yes I'm planning on checking that later, when it works. :)

Comment: Start using mysqli_prepare statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have a look at this: 
[MySQL Insert Where query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query)

You don't want to insert, but update a record. You always insert a complete row - not a single column of an existing row. You use update for that. Therefore there is no need to use where when inserting.

Lookking at your problem it should be something like

```
UPDATE users SET location = $_POST["location"] where social_id = $_SESSION["FBID"]
```

As mentioned in the comment above you should, however still escape at least the location variable before inserting it.

Have a look at "mysql prepared statements"

Comment: Thanks for reply, it works. What is meant by "escape"?

Comment: Means Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection.Read this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the string before inserting it into the database to prevent MySQL injection. Assigning it to a variable would be easier.

Also, I think you are trying to update the row, use UPDATE query instead of INSERT.

```
$FBID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION["FBID"])
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["location"])

$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `location` =  '$location' WHERE `social_id`='$FBID' ";
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm actually passing the variables to a function in another file. Should the escaping be done in the function then? Or in the if isset which calls the funtion?

Comment: @FelixF. You're welcome! Both are fine, although escaping it before passing it into the function would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Please always prepare your query, never use a $_POST or any other user input value directly in your query to prevent SQL injection.

**SQL Injection is more dangerous then you think**

If you insert $_POST["location"] = "'' -- " into @Frank Provost's code, then you will **UPDATE all the rows** instead of the one with the FBID session key.

**Multiple queries with SQL Injection**

If you have multi query enabled then you can insert $_POST["location"] = "''; DROP TABLE users -- " into @Frank Provost's code, then you will **DROP the table users**.

**Always use prepared statements**

You can take a look at my PDO implementation example on GitHub:
https://github.com/maartensch/database-pdo-mysql-class-php

Example code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourTablename(id,name) VALUES(:id,:name)";
$userInputId = 'yourUnescapedValue';
$userInputName = 'yourUnescapedValue';
$preparedStatements = array(':id'=>$userInputId,':name'=>$userInputName);
Db::getDb()->query($sql,$preparedStatements);
```