# Insert query with WHERE condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to insert data into mysql table with some where condition. But it makes some error which is

```
error on queryYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
```

---

I have tried following query,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $type=$_POST['leave_type'];
    $division=$_POST['division'];
    $number_of_date=$_POST['number_of_date'];

    $resul=mysql_query("SELECT * from employee where (division='$division' || division='all_dpt')") or die("query error".mysql_error());
    $result3 = mysql_fetch_array($resul);
    $emp_division=$result3['division'];
    $id=$result3['emp_id'];
    $annual_additional=$result3['annual_additional'];

    $value=$annual_additional+$number_of_date;

    if(($division==$emp_division || $division='all_dpt') && $type='Annual'){
        $result1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO employee (annual_additional) VALUES ('$value') WHERE emp_id='$id'")or die("error on query".mysql_error());
    }}
```

---

How can I fix it, please help !

Comment: Why need `Insert ... Where`, Use `Update .... Where`

Comment: Check some sample: [mysql-insert-where-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query)

Comment: Insert statements have no where clause. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can't use a WHERE condition in an INSERT query. So either remove the WHERE part or change to UPDATE.

Comment: How can `INSERT` have `where` clause, may be you should try `UPDATE` instead.......

Comment: Yep, But it does not work even using UPDATE

Comment: Do you maintain the `UPDATE` format properly?? Show us the UPDATE query.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT WARNING:** mysql_query was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include mysqli_query() and PDO::query()

**FOR EDUCATIONAL PURPOSES**: this is how your code should look if you are using mysql_query:

```
//you should definitely create a function that sanitizes the users input
//so that you don't get hacked via sql injection:
$value = sanitize($value);
$id= sanitize($id);

$sql = "UPDATE employee SET annual_additional = '$value' 
WHERE emp_id='$id'";
if (!result = mysql_query($sql))
{
    die("query error".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Definitely, now I have fixed my problem by this way, thank u

Comment: @Chathurika awesome no problem! Oh and if this answer is the one that worked for you, please accept it (with a green checkmark) so that users know it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `INSERT.....WHERE`, For Updating a row you need `UPDATE....WHERE`.

If you have the condition that you need to insert and if the `key` isn't exist then use the given example.

Demo for example:

```
INSERT INTO Users (id, weight, desiredWeight) VALUES(1, 160, 145) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight=160, desiredWeight=145
```

**Collected from:** [MySQL Insert Where query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query)

Answer (score 1):

with witch query you get the error?Insert? 
Futhermore, use mysql_real_escape_string or this: http://pear.php.net/package/DB for your querys.

Answer (score 1):

You Should Use 'UPDATE' instead of 'INSERT'

```
UPDATE employee SET `annual_additional`='$value' WHERE `emp_id`='$id'
```

Hope It will Work.