# How to INSERT / WHERE NOT EXIST in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problems with the next sentence:

```
INSERT INTO `pasajeros` 
( 
    `nombre`,
    `apellidos`,
    `email`,
    `password`,
    `telefono`
) 
VALUES 
(
    'Alexandra',
    'Gonzalez',
    'cesa@cesar3.com',
    '1234567!',
    '04242344556' 
) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    `transportistas` 
    WHERE   `email` = 'cesa@cesar3.com'
);
```

What's wrong in my code? I need to make an Insert if a email is not used in another table. That was my approach, but I can't figure it out why my query fails.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `transportistas` WHERE `email` = 'cesa@cesar3.c' at line 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can use `Values` with a `where` clause. But you can insert using a `select` statement which can handle a `where` clause just fine.

```
INSERT INTO `pasajeros` 
( 
    `nombre`,
    `apellidos`,
    `email`,
    `password`,
    `telefono`
) 
Select * from (
select 
     'Alexandra' as `nombre`,
     'Gonzalez' as `apellidos`,
     'cesa@cesar3.com' as `email`,
     '1234567!' as `password` ,
     '04242344556' as `telefono`
    ) i
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    `transportistas` 
    WHERE   `email` = i.email
);
```

Comment: "`nombre` =  'Alexandra'" - I dont believe that works. You should get an error like "unknown column `nombre`"

Comment: @that kind of thing would work in SQL server...and I never really do MySQL. Can you only use `as` to alias?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thats correct Paul. I'm getting these error, how can I fix it?

Comment: @Brad The updated version should work. However - you don't even need any aliases here.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, yes I know they are not required but I do like to have them for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do what you want is to define a unique index/constraint:

```
create unique index unq_pasajeros_email on pasajeros(email);
```

The *database* will then protect the data.

This is much better than trying to do this at the application layer, because it prevents duplication if someone manually updates the data.

Comment: What means unq_pasajeros_email? The email must to be unique in both `pasajeros` and `transportistas` tables, the field in both cases is called `email`

Comment: @CesarJrRodriguez . . . Then you need two unique indexes, one for each table.  However, your question only concerns `pasajeros`.