# PHP SQL Execute Statement returning False

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a basic SQL statement, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the context:
I have a database named: **my_database**
a table named: **users**
Two columns: **service_id** which type is **BIGINT**
and **video_id** which type is **varchar(20)**

Here is my code:

```
$video_id = "chartext";
$service_id = 12345678910;
$bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=moods_db", "user", "pass");
$query = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO users(video_id) VALUES (?) WHERE service_id = $service_id");
$query->execute([$service_id]);
var_dump($req->execute([$video_id]));
// which gives me false
```

Some info:
My PHP_INT_MAX gives me 9223372036854775807

I am aware of SQL Injection and just removed it to be clearer

I var_dumped each steps and the execute one is the only one that is not working

I ran the statement in phpmyadmin console and it told me: "Syntax error near 'WHERE (service_id = '12345678910')' line 1

I also searched the usage of WHERE Clause but I did not understand if I could put it in an INSERT statement, I think I already did that and it worked, I am lost

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such syntax. What is this code **supposed** to do?

Comment: I think you answer by your own "I also searched the usage of WHERE Clause but I did not understand if I could put it in an INSERT statement".

Comment: Did not see `$req->` when answering question, where does `$req` come from? It should be `UPDATE SET`

Comment: There is no WHERE clause on an INSERT. Insert adds a new row to a table, unless it breaks some other reference rule

Comment: _Big Note_ If you are going to use a bound parameter for `video_id` why not also do that for `service_id`

Comment: @Mureinik is it supposed to insert a video id in a row that matches the service id given

Comment: As already mentioned, INSERT has no WHERE clause.
What you are trying to do can only be accomplished with REPLACE INTO.
This will insert a new record, if it doesn't exist, or replace the record if it exists.
I suggest you try learning more about SQL before trying to do anything of importance with it, as this is very basic knowledge that you are required to have in order to not destroy any data. For starters, your WHERE clause should return 1 or 0 rows, otherwise you run the risk of overwriting all your data (i.e., service_id should be a PRIMARY KEY).

Comment: @Jaquarh req was the french for 'requete' which means query, yes I found it after thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PDOStatement::execute** — Executes a prepared statement. It returns **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on failure.

So for your case it is returning **FALSE** because In an `INSERT` statement you wouldn't have an **existing** row to do a `WHERE` clause.

*You need to try like this way to insert one row with two values or use UPDATE query to update one row with one value based on another value on the existing row. Hope it clears your doubts now :)*

```
$video_id = "chartext";
$service_id = 12345678910;
$bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=moods_db", "user", "pass");
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(video_id, service_id) VALUES (?,?)";
$array = array($video_id , $service_id );
$sth = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($array);
var_dump($sth);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, Im not sure I understood this example, it looks like it Inserts 2 values instead of one and not where it should be, sorry for the mess I found the answer just then, thanks !

Comment: @Narek glad it helps you somehow. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't use WHERE Clause with INSERT TO.
Here are some answers, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913305/7183227  https://stackoverflow.com/a/485057/7183227
from [MySQL Insert Where query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query/485062)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you have written INSERT query.  INSERT query does not contain where clause.

You have to update it your query as follows:

INSERT INTO users(video_id) VALUES (?)

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use WHERE clause in INSERT query. so, either perform INSERT (it does not have WHERE) or try UPDATE where you can use WHERE clause. just visit here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert if you want to insert the record or here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/update if you want to update and check the syntax and perform it properly. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped :)

Comment: glad to know it helped you. :) you can vote me up