# Creating log table to register records MySql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a `log` table for my DB that register all the actions that happen, and I was thinking of creating one log table for each table so I'll be able to read the information easily.
But I'm not sure how to do it because I want the input of the `log` table to a variable where I'll format the text and put the other variables to register the input.
Eg: `$log = '[' . $data_log . '] ' . ' The item '. $ativo .' with the S/N '. $numero_serie .' was delivered to the employee '. $id_colaborador);`

And for the DB I have this, I know it's wrong but I don't know why..

```
if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $acao_log2 = '[' . $data_log . '] ' . ' O ativo '. $ativo .' com o S/N '. $numero_serie .' foi entregue ao colaborador '. $id_colaborador . ' [' . $user . ']' ; 



    $sql = "INSERT INTO ativos (ativo,comentario,data_aquisicao,localizacao,fabricante,modelo,imei,
            numero_serie,ativo_sap,evento,data_evento,id_colaborador) 
            SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, id_colaborador 
            FROM colaboradores 
            WHERE nome = ?";



    $log = "INSERT INTO log_ativos (acao_log, data_log, id_ativo)
            VALUES (". $acao_log2 . "," . $data_log . ", id_ativo = id_ativo WHERE id_ativo = ?";

    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $qlog = $pdo->prepare($log);
    $q->execute(array($ativo,$comentario,$data_aquisicao,$localizacao,$fabricante,$modelo,$imei,$numero_serie,$ativo_sap,$evento,$data_evento,$id_colaborador));
    $qlog->execute(array($acao_log,$data_log,$id_ativo));
    Database::disconnect();
```

The thing is, I dont want the user to input nothing for the logs, it should be automatic :/

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Ativos\create.php:129 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Ativos\create.php(129): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Ativos\create.php on line 129

Comment: What is this `SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, id_colaborador`  columns and tables name can't be replaced by placeholder

Comment: That `SELECT` works with no erros, it only has problems on the `$log` because before I try the `INSERT` on the `log table` it worked with no problems

Comment: No it's wrong.. Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.

Comment: Listen, It's working that way, if I remove the `$log` it does not give me any error and sucefully creates the register on the DB.

Comment: It's wrong period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries are wrong in so many levels.

1. `SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, id_colaborador`  This really [wrong Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)
2. Your Insert query is wrong also :

   `$log = "INSERT INTO log_ativos (acao_log, data_log, id_ativo)
             VALUES (". $acao_log2 . "," . $data_log . ", id_ativo = id_ativo WHERE id_ativo = ?";`

The above query is so wrong.. [INSERT does not support where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query), instead you are looking at update.

This is what you might be looking for.

```
<?php
if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $acao_log2 = '[' . $data_log . '] ' . ' O ativo ' . $ativo . ' com o S/N ' . $numero_serie . ' foi entregue ao colaborador ' . $id_colaborador . ' [' . $user . ']';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ativos (ativo,comentario,data_aquisicao,localizacao,fabricante,modelo,imei,
            numero_serie,ativo_sap,evento,data_evento,id_colaborador) 
            SELECT column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10,column11, id_colaborador 
            FROM colaboradores 
            WHERE nome = ?";

    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($nomeVariable));

    $log  = "UPDATE log_ativos SET acao_log = ? , data_log = ? WHERE id_ativo = ? ";
    $qlog = $pdo->prepare($log);
    $qlog->execute(array($id_ativo));

}

?>
```

Take sometime and do sql quires tutorials and be friend with php manual and sql manual

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment from below,

> I want to create a new log record for that table based on the
>   id_ativo that the 1st query will generate,

Then what you need to do when the 1st statement inserted successfully get the [last insert  id](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) that was generate and use in the next insert.

This is how :

```
<?php

if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $acao_log2 = '[' . $data_log . '] ' . ' O ativo ' . $ativo . ' com o S/N ' . $numero_serie . ' foi entregue ao colaborador ' . $id_colaborador . ' [' . $user . ']';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ativos (ativo,comentario,data_aquisicao,localizacao,fabricante,modelo,imei,
            numero_serie,ativo_sap,evento,data_evento,id_colaborador) 
            SELECT column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10,column11, id_colaborador 
            FROM colaboradores 
            WHERE nome = ?";

    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($nomeVariable));

    if ($q) {
        //get last ID that was generated by previos insert
        $id_ativo = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    }

    $log  = "INSERT INTO log_ativos (acao_log,data_log,id_ativo) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    $qlog = $pdo->prepare($log);
    $qlog->execute(array($acao_log2,$data_log,$id_ativo));

}

?>
```

Comment: 1st I don't want to update the `log_ativos` I want to create a new `log record` for that table based on the `id_ativo` that the 1st query will generate, and when I'm saying that it works the way it is it's because I'm testing it many and many times and it does not give me any problem man... The only issue I'm having is with the `$log` query!

Comment: You don't use a where clause on `INSERT..` use that in `UPDATE,DELETE,SELECT`

Comment: I understand that, but I can't update a record that does not exist, I've already understand that the `$log` query is wrong and thanks for advice me, But the other above it's working with no problems, I'm only having problems with creating the `$log` register

Comment: I need to replace the `column1...` for the respective names, but what it's the `$q->execute(array($nomeVariable));` variable? The `FK` ?

Comment: `WHERE nome = ? ` is  variable  holds the data of nome

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ativo' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Ativos\create.php:120 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Ativos\create.php(120): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Ativos\create.php on line 120`

Comment: looks like you don't have `ativo` in your columns

Comment: `ativo` is the principal field of `ativos` table.

Comment: Let's say I needed to get both of my and your code, your `if ($q) {
        //get last ID that was generated by previos insert
        $id_ativo = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    }

    $log  = "INSERT INTO log_ativos (acao_log,data_log,id_ativo) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    $qlog = $pdo->prepare($log);
    $qlog->execute(array($acao_log2,$data_log,$id_ativo));` was totally right and that's what I was missing, thanks a lot for real and thanks for the advices too!

Comment: sorry for bother u again, for the update will be a little different, right?

Comment: @CarlosSantiago yes update is different check the 1st example