# SQL in Java. How to INSERT INTO Derby table with WHERE condition

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I have derby database with table TRIPS. I have 10 columns, but 2 columns:FAIR and TIP should be inserted separately (later when trip on taxi is finished).

Can you please help me to adjust SQL code?

I have this code and it is not working now:

```
public boolean saveInDB2(String id, String amount, String tip) {
        String writeString = "INSERT INTO TRIPS(FAIR, TIP) VALUES ('" + amount +"', '"+ tip +"')" + "WHERE ID = '"+ id +"'";
        try {
            st.executeUpdate(writeString);
        } catch (SQLException sqle){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? If you're *inserting* twice, that's not an insert on the 2nd run, it's an *update*

Comment: Don't concatenate strings. Use parameters (`?`) instead. Otherwise, your code can be weak and susceptible to SQL Injection.

Comment: How to correct use parameter "?"

Comment: sleepToken, I'm not getting any errors. And connection is ok. I'm able to INSERT other data for other columns

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not an error but a security warning. To create secure SQL Statements your queries should rely on Preparedstatements.
You can find some Details here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Anna, can you teel us what are you trying to archieve? I guess you need to perform two separated queries, one for insert and other for update. To your information using insert into <table> (<columns>) values (<values>) doesn't goes with a where clause, you are mixing things wrong. An insert with where clause is more like this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp. Also consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query. Finally (in order to recap) you can read this: https://www.dofactory.com/sql/insert

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Answer (score 1):

Typically for an existing row, you wouldn't use an `INSERT`, but rather would use an `UPDATE` statement. `INSERT` statements are for new records.

Insert: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp
Update: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp