# I'm using an INSERT query to insert in mysql table, there's an error in my syntax

Tags: python, mysql

```
x = self.npprocess_PTE.text()
    y = 123
    if len(self.npprocess_PTE.text()) == 0:
       print("yes") 
    else:
       model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
       self.npprocessview_LV.setModel(model)
       z = model.rowCount()
       z = z + 1
       a = str(z)+'_Process'
       b = "INSERT INTO new_part_info(%s) VALUES(%s) WHERE Part_ID = %s"
       c = (z, x, y)
       mycursor.execute(b, c)
       mydb.commit()
```

The error i am getting:u have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1) VALUES('wb') WHERE Part_ID = 123' at line 1

Comment: insert statement does not accept where condition,remove the where condition and try

Comment: ...although that doesn't account for the error message

Comment: You can't use where with insert . See more here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/485062/7867026

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors that I can see in your insert query:

1. As others pointed out, `insert` statement does not have a `where` clause. Either you need to get rid of it, or you need to change the `insert` into an `update`. However, this is **not** the error that causes the error message.
2. You use `z` variable as the name of the column for the insert. `z` is a number. As mysql manual on [object identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) says:

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

So, you need to quote the value in `z`:

```
w = '`' + str(z) + '`'
```

and then use `w` insted of `z` when executing the `insert`. Alternatively, you need to use `a` variable instead of `z`, since it is created as:

```
a = str(z)+'_Process'
```

It depends on the name of the columns within your table, really.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shadow. Cleared all my doubts