# INSERT query is not working on the addition of WHERE clause in SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So to sum up my problem and what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to code an Attendance feature in my PHP Website where the admin first chooses the Class he wants to mark the Attendance for, and then he's taken to a new page with a table that ONLY displays students from THAT class. He enter the date/status of each student and presses Submit, and multiple rows are inserted into the "attendance" table.

Now, this was working perfectly before. The only new addition to this feature was the "Class" feature, now each student has a class (you might call it grade in your region). Before, they didn't.

So naturally, the table's SELECT query went from

```
$rows2 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM students")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to:

```
$rows2 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE grade_id = $grade")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This little addition has completely messed up my INSERT query, which works fine when I exclude the "WHERE" clause. Below, I'm attaching code for two pages - one is **ChooseClass.php** where admin picks the Class he wants to add Attendance for. This page basically sends the chosen class ID to the 2nd page, which is **AddAttendance.php**.

**ChooseClass.php**:

```
<?php include('../db.php');
session_start();

$email = $_SESSION["email"];
$user = $conn->query("SELECT * from admin where email = '$email' ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$userID = $user[0]['admin_id'];



$someotherRow = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM grade")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php include('adminheader.php'); ?>

<body style="background-color: #5e72e4 !important;">
    <!-- Sidenav -->
    <?php include('adminsidebar.php'); ?>
    <div class="main-content" id="panel">
        <!-- Topnav -->
        <?php include('admintopbar.php'); ?>
        <!-- Header -->
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="header bg-primary pb-6" style="background-color: #5e72e4 !important;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="header-body">
                    <div class="row align-items-center py-4">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-7">
                            <h6 class="h2 text-white d-inline-block mb-0">Attendance Managament</h6>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Card stats -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="card">
                                <!-- Card body -->
                                <div class="card-header">Choose a Class</div>
                                <div class="card-body">

                                <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 600px;">
                                                <table class="table align-items-center table-dark table-flush">
                                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                                        <tr>

                                                            <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="name">Class Name</th>
                                                            <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="status">Action</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody class="list">
                                                        <?php
                                                        foreach ($someotherRow as $row) { ?>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                
                                                                <th scope="row">
                                                                    <div class="media align-items-center">

                                                                        <div class="media-body">
                                                                            <span class="name mb-0 text-sm"><?php echo $row['grade_name']; ?></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </th>

                                                                <td>
                                                                 <form action="" method="POST">
                                                                      <a type="submit"  href="adminmarkattendance.php?gradeid=<?php echo $row['grade_id'];  ?> " class="btn  btn-primary">Select</a>
                                                                 </form>
                                                                </td>
                                                                

                                                            </tr>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                            </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Page content -->
            <div class="container-fluid mt--6">
                <!-- background-color: #5e72e4 !important; height: 63.9vh; -->
            </div>
        </div>
       
</body>

</html>
```

**AddAttendance.php**:

```
<?php include('../db.php');
session_start();

$email = $_SESSION["email"];

$user = $conn->query("SELECT * from admin where email = '$email' ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$userID = $user[0]['admin_id'];

$grade = 0;

if (isset($_GET['gradeid'])) {
    $grade = $_GET['gradeid'];
}

$rows2 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE grade_id = $grade")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$count = count($rows2);

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $student_id = $_POST["id"][$i];
        $status = $_POST['options'][$i];
        
        $grade_id = $_POST['grade_id'];
        $date = $_POST['attendancedate'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

        $queryInsert = $conn->prepare("INSERT
       into attendance
       (
       student_id,
       grade_id,
       date,
       status
       )
       values 
       (
       $student_id,
       $grade_id,
       '$date',
       '$status'
       )
        ");
        $queryInsert->execute();

        
    }



    echo "<script> location.replace('chooseclass.php'); </script>";
}




?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php include('adminheader.php'); ?>

<body style="background-color: #5e72e4 !important;">
    <!-- Sidenav -->
    <?php include('adminsidebar.php'); ?>
    <div class="main-content" id="panel">
        <!-- Topnav -->
        <?php include('admintopbar.php'); ?>
        <!-- Header -->
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="header bg-primary pb-6" style="background-color: #5e72e4 !important;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="header-body">
                    <div class="row align-items-center py-4">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-7">
                            <h6 class="h2 text-white d-inline-block mb-0">Mark Attendance</h6>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Card stats -->


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <form action="adminmarkattendance.php" method="post">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="card bg-default shadow">
                                            <div class="card-header bg-transparent border-0">

                                                <div class="form-inline">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                        <h3 class="text-white mb-0">Registered Students</h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <input style="width: 100%;" class="form-control" name="attendancedate" type="date" required>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 600px;">
                                                <table class="table align-items-center table-dark table-flush">
                                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                                        <tr>

                                                            <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="name">Avatar</th>
                                                            <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="name">Student Name</th>
                                                            <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="status">Phone Number</th>
                                                            <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="status">Age</th>
                                                            <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="status">Gender</th>
                                                            <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="status">Address</th>
                                                            <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="status">Action</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody class="list">
                                                        <?php
                                                        foreach ($rows2 as $row) { ?>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <img src="<?php echo '../profileImages/' . $row['profile_image'] ?>" width="45" height="45" alt="">
                                                                    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>">
                                                                    <input type="hidden" name="grade_id" value="<?php echo $grade ?>">
                                                                </td>
                                                                <th scope="row">
                                                                    <div class="media align-items-center">

                                                                        <div class="media-body">
                                                                            <span class="name mb-0 text-sm"><?php echo $row['fname'] . ' ' . $row['lname']; ?></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </th>

                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">
                                                                        <span class="status"><?php echo $row['phonenumber']; ?></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">
                                                                        <span class="status"><?php echo $row['age']; ?></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">
                                                                        <span class="status"><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">
                                                                        <span class="status"><?php echo $row['address']; ?></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="options[]">
                                                                            <option value="Present" selected>Present</option>
                                                                            <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </td>

                                                            </tr>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-warning">Mark Attendance</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Page content -->
            <div class="container-fluid mt--6">
                <!-- background-color: #5e72e4 !important; height: 63.9vh; -->
            </div>
        </div>
      
</body>

</html>
```

I've spent 2 hours looking at this code and I can't figure out why the addition of WHERE breaks my code. I've also var_dumped **most** of the variables, just to check if I was entering some NULL value and I'm not. So kindly look into it and see if you can figure out why data is not being inserted into the database..

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Unrelated fyi: you don't need a `<form>` element around the `<a type="submit" ...>Select</a>`. And the `<a>` element doesn't use a `type="submit"` attribute

Comment: well when inserting data you can't use WHERE...but if you're updating you can ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-query-doesnt-work-with-where-clause this might help you

Answer (score 0):

You are sending gradeid value in -
href="**adminmarkattendance.php**?gradeid= "

And getting value in **AddAttendance.php**
So, first give right path and second, there is also a space within ahref. So, when you try to get the value use trim, it will remove spaces -

```
$grade = trim($_GET['gradeid']);
```

Comment: It's adminmarkattendance.php in both instances, I made a mistake in the post. As for the space, the grade is working perfectly fine and even works when I remove the WHERE clause from the SELECT query. Though I still tried and the result is the same, unfortunately.

Comment: echo this line "SELECT * FROM students WHERE grade_id = '$grade'" and see what's going on $grade

Comment: I did, it echoes the correct grade ID every time. It even alerts the correct grade ID when I do it inside the if(isset($_POST['submit'])). So grade ID is definitely working as it should. So is student ID & date. Like I said, all this info goes in the database flawlessly unless I add the WHERE clause in the SELECT statement, for some odd reason..